# Excel VBA Application.Match - Multiple Matches Via Array & Discerning The Correct Match

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, csv, string-matching

I am encountering an issue when using VBA's Application.Match function. To give background context, my objective is to create code that loops through names in Column B of an Excel Spreadsheet, matches a name to an array that contains names, return its index value, take that index value and plug in into an array containing genders and return either M or F which then is used to write either Mr. or Ms. to the corresponding cell in Column A. As you can see in my below code, this works flawlessly. My code is as follows (simplified with no CSV input but rather hard-coded values):

```
    namearr = Array("John", "Julia", Tom", "Julia")
    genderarr = Array("M", "M", "M", "F")
    occurrancearr = Array(15000, 5, 9000, 11000)
        If titletoolinput = 6 Then
                    iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                    For iRow = 1 To iRowL
                        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 2)) Then
                            nameindex = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 2).Value, namearr, 0)
                            Debug.Print nameindex
                            If IsError(nameindex) Then
                                Cells(iRow, 1) = ""
                            Else
                                genderoutput = genderarr(1, nameindex)
                                Debug.Print genderoutput
                                If genderoutput = "M" Then
                                    Cells(iRow, 1) = "Mr."
                                ElseIf genderoutput = "F" Then
                                    Cells(iRow, 1) = "Ms."
                                Else
                                    Cells(iRow, 1) = ""
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next iRow
                  Else
                  End If
```

The issue I am trying to resolve happens when there is more than one name in the array. Since the arrays will be populated with a CSV file containing Census information with over 17,000 names from names given at birth, there has been instances where a a blatantly single-gender name has come up in both the male and female category. Now the CSV data also provides how many occurrences the name was used (for example: Julia as Female name = 11000 instances / Julia as Male name = 5 instances) and I have put these values in the "occurancearr" Array. What I want to do is have Application.Match return all matches of the name if there is more than one, then use those matches' indexes to pull the occurrence data, see which number is greater (I am assuming that a name with more occurrences means its likely the most popular gender for the name), return the index of only the match with the highest occurrence and use that index to get the correct gender. This example scenario with "Julia" can be seen in my demo arrays in the sample code where it would return the wrong gender if run.

As of yet, I have tried endlessly and cannot find an efficient way to do so through my own experience, on the internet or on Stack Overflow. Is there any simple and least verbose way to accomplish this  (as this has to be coded multiple times in If Loops)? Without a solution, this code cannot work as it produces wrong gender values when run. Please let me know if my objective or examples are unclear. Any help with this would be very, very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you sort your data (by name and then #of occurences descending) before loading it then you can just take the first match for each name.

Comment: @TimWilliams True! I haven't thought about doing this, despite its simplicity. By using this method, is there a chance for any inadvertent "side affects" or issues that you can think of? Or is this pretty fool-proof in your opinion?

Comment: If your requirement is to select the "most used" instance of each name to determine the gender, then it seems OK to me.